# Visual Studio 2015 compiles typescript class into javascript class

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio, if I save a typescript file that contains a class, the compiled JavaScript file also contains class (looks it compiles to ES6 rather than ES5). However if I build from the build menu, it compiles to function constructor.

I am trying this in a Node.js console application.

How do I get Ctrs+S to generate ES5 compliance JavaScript?

Comment: tsconfig.json has `"target": "es5"`?

Comment: there was no tsconfig.josn file in the project. I added 1 with target to es5, but it didn't help

Comment: Visual Studio is normally configured to trigger  preprocessors/compilers for a number of file types, e.g. LESS and SASS. As soon as a file gets saved, changes are detected and output (CSS in this case) is generated. Same applies to TypeScript. As soon as .ts file gets saved, a VS extension detects the change and triggers compilation in to .js file. My issue is that when I compile manually, it compiles to right ES edition, but compilation triggered by file save compiles to a different ES edition. I am looking for a configuration option or something so it gets compiled to ES5 in all cases.